# What happened to the Titans after the Survey Corps left the walls?

Tags: attack-on-titan

What happened to all the Titans roaming outside the walls when the Survey Corps left the wall and arrived at the ocean? I mean, surely they couldn't not have disappeared into thin air now (Like the Colossal Titan), right? Surely the Survey Corps would have encountered vast amounts of Titans as always when venturing outside the walls.

I know for a fact that the Survey Corps did not install Titan guillotines all over Wall Maria, like it was used in Trost District.

I distinctly remember in one of the chapters, it mentioned that the Survey Corps went along beaten Titan trails outside of the walls, and encountering little to no Titan Resistance. How is this possible? Am I missing something from the Manga/Anime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is described in chapter 90 of manga. Using Titan guillotines, survey corps eventually slayed all titans inside wall Maria. And in following expedition to outside the walls, survey corps made conclusion, that most titans were actually inside wall Maria, so close to no titans were left in total.

Comment: How did I miss that? Heck, beats me. But it does make sense, the Titans can get even closer now to Humans thanks to the breach in Wall Maria by Shiganshina, which make sense for them to cluster into Wall Maria in the hopes of breaching Wall Rose. Thanks again! Really do appreciate it!